# Python JSON Formatting for Redis Cache

Tags: python, json, dictionary, redis

I'm relatively new to working with JSON and am trying to output a dictionary to JSON using the json library in python. The issue I have is the format is very specific and I'm not sure how to approach. Specifically the desired format has extra braces and brackets. Below is an example of the dictionary I'm converting to JSON and the desired output:

```
    #Sample Data
sample_dict = {"office":{"50":"pencil;paper",
                      "100":"stapler;eraser"},
             "warehouse":{"50":"forklift;wrench",
                         "100":"truck,screw"}}

with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(sample_dict, f,indent = 4)

##Output I'm able to acheive
{
    "office": {
        "50": "pencil;paper",
        "100": "stapler;eraser"
    },
    "warehouse": {
        "50": "forklift;wrench",
        "100": "truck,screw"
    }
}


##Desired Output
[{
    {"office": {
        "50": "pencil;paper",
        "100": "stapler;eraser"
    }},
    {"warehouse": {
        "50": "forklift;wrench",
        "100": "truck,screw"
    }}
}]
```

Comment: You will need to post the exact specifications you need, not just a sample. Its wrapped in ```[...]```. Is this for the top level only? Why is "office" and "warehouse" wrapped in brackets but not the quantities?

Comment: Could you double check your desired output for us? Right now, it's a list with a dictionary in it that doesn't have a key/value pair, but it contains two sub-dictionaries each with a dictionary of two key/value pairs. Was your intention to have a list of 1 dictionary that contains 2 keys (office, warehouse) with the values being nested dictionaries, as per Steven M's answer?

Comment: The desired output is correct...I did get a little more background on the output...it's meant to be stored in a Redis Cache. Maybe that explains the extra {}?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the "sample_dict" a string with square brackets.

```
import json

sample_dict = '[{"office":{"50":"pencil;paper", "100":"stapler;eraser"}, "warehouse":{"50":"forklift;wrench", "100":"truck,screw"}}]'

load=json.loads(sample_dict)
print(json.dumps(load, indent=4))
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

The extra `[]` would be easy — the whole dictionary is in a list. However, the extra `{}` are not; the sample you posted is not, in fact, valid JSON.

At this point, you'll need to clarify whether the output should be JSON or whether it should match the given sample.

- If the output should be JSON, you'll need to get a correct sample output, then work from there. At a minimum, the top level is a list of dictionaries.
- If the output should match the given sample, it's not JSON and you won't be using the `json` library. Depending on the situation, you can:

  - format it up with Python string formatting (`%` or `.format()` or `f"..."` strings); or
  - use a templating library like [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) or [Mako](https://www.makotemplates.org/) or similar; or
  - if the data structure is extensive and the format is consistent, write your own library for outputting that format.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! Would it make a difference if the JSON was meant for a Redis Cache?

Comment: Well, in Redis you'll be storing strings, so the question is what's going to be reading it out of Redis. If it's going to be the your own program, probably best to use standard JSON (without the extra `{}`). If it's going to be some other program, you'll need to check what exact format it expects.